# How to wait on a Mutex with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I've a for loop that will launch processes in parallel every launched process will return a response back indicating that it is ready. I want to wait for the response and I'll abort if a certain timeout is reached.

Development environment is VS2008
Here is the pseudo code:

```
void executeCommands(std::vector<Command*> commands)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++)
    {
        Command* cmd = commands[i];
        DWORD pid = ProcessLauncher::launchProcess(cmd->getWorkingDirectory(),  cmd->getCommandToExcecute(), cmd->params);

        //Should I wait for process to become ready?
        if (cmd->getWaitStatusTimeout() > 0)
        {
            ProcessStatusManager::getInstance().addListener(*this);

            //TODO: emit process launching signal

            //BEGINNING OF QUESTION
            //I don't how to do this part. 
            //I might use QT's QWaitCondition but if there is another solution in omp
            //I'd like to use it
            bool timedOut;
            SOMEHANDLE handle = Openmp::waitWithTimeout(cmd->getWaitStatusTimeout(), &timedOut);
            mWaitConditions[pid]) = handle;
            //END OF QUESTION

            if (timedOut)
            {
                ProcessStatusManager::getInstance().removeListener(*this);
                //TODO: kill process
                //TODO: emit fail signal
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO: emit process ready signal
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: emit process ready signal
        }
    }
}

void onProcessReady(DWORD sourceProcessPid)
{
    ProcessStatusManager::getInstance().removeListener(*this);
    SOMEHANDLE handle = mWaitConditions[sourceProcessPid];
    if (mWaitConditions[sourceProcessPid] != 0)
    {
        Openmp::wakeAll(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.openmp.org/pipermail/omp/2007/000647.html

Comment: @aaa Then I'm assuming using QMutex & QWaitCondition for my case is a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment above pointed out, Michael Suess did present a paper on adding this functionality to OpenMP.  He is the last of several people that have proposed adding some type of wait function to OpenMP.  The OpenMP language committee has taken the issue up several times.  Each time it has been rejected because there are other ways to do this function already.  I don't know Qt, but as long as the functions it provides are thread safe, then you should be able to use them.